# Generate PDF with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdf, fpdf

how generate PDF document with MYSQL query more than 15 fields with wrap text? I have generated PDF with fpdf option. but I have created only 8 fields with nowrap text. so any one please solve the solutions. thanks.

For example. I have created with nowrap text.

```
$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);
$pdf->SetTextColor(4,126,167);
$pdf->Cell(10,10,'Worksheet Report');
$pdf->Ln();

//Column titles
$header=array('Client','Team In Charge','Staff In Charge','Priority','Master Activity','Sub Activity','Last Reports Sent','Job in Hand','Team Incharge Notes','External Due Date','Befree Due Date','Status');
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',6);
$pdf->FancyTable($header);

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',5);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255,255,255);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(.2);
$sql=$_SESSION['query'];
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row = @mysql_fetch_array($result)){
$pdf->Cell(15,10,htmlspecialchars($row["lp_wrk_CompanyName"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Cell(17,10,$commonUses->getFirstLastName($row["wrk_TeamInCharge"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Cell(17,10,$commonUses->getFirstLastName($row["wrk_StaffInCharge"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Cell(12,10,htmlspecialchars($row["lp_wrk_priority"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Cell(17,10,htmlspecialchars($row["lp_wrk_MasCode"]).($row["lp_wrk_MasCode"]!=""? "-":"").htmlspecialchars($row["lp_wrk_MasterActivity"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Cell(15,10,htmlspecialchars($row["lp_wrk_SubCode"]).($row["lp_wrk_SubCode"]!=""? "-":"").htmlspecialchars($row["lp_wrk_SubActivity"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Cell(19,10,htmlspecialchars($row["wrk_Details"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Cell(18,10,htmlspecialchars($row["wrk_Notes"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Cell(19,10,htmlspecialchars($row["wrk_TeamInChargeNotes"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Cell(18,10,$commonUses->showGridDateFormat($row["wrk_DueDate"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Cell(18,10,$commonUses->showGridDateFormat($row["wrk_InternalDueDate"]),1,0,'T',true);

$pdf->Cell(15,10,htmlspecialchars($row["lp_wrk_Status"]),1,0,'T',true);
$pdf->Ln();
}
```

Comment: how did you do it for 8 fields and nowrap text?

Answer (score 3):

There's a webservice called [DocRaptor](http://www.docraptor.com) that uses Prince to generate pdf and xls from html. They offer a free plan as well as larger paid plans.

Answer (score 0):

check this web link :-
http://qualitypoint.blogspot.com/2010/07/resolved-wrap-text-issue-in-fpdf-table.html
http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/how-to-create-pdf-files-with-php/

I hope it is useful for you :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [dompdf](http://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) class.  It generates the pdf from your html code so it's much easier and quicker to get the results you want.  It's still a bit finicky with floats so you have to imagine your are in the 90's and do a table based design.

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to print out the table in html, than convert in into pdf: is easier, faster, and more flexible: when you have the html documents, will be easy (for example) convert into a jpg, if you'll need to in the future.

If you can install software on your server, i raccomend you [wkhtmltopdf](http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/).

You generate the html file, and wkhtmltopdf convert it to pdf, with full (webkit based) css support.

Else, i've found that [html2ps](http://www.tufat.com/s_html2ps_html2pdf.htm) doeas a great job, but is quite slower with large files.. css support is good, but no guarantee that it will support css3, for example.